# How to store and load User with Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter4j

In Twitter4j, you get a user object like following,

```
User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
```

Now, I want to store this user in a text file. I'm using the `toString()` method of the `User`.

It gives me something like the following:

```
UserJSONImpl{id=xxxxxx, name='xxxx xxxxx', screenName='xxxxxx', ... }
```

Questions:

1. Is using `toString()` method of `User` for storing purposes legitimate?
2. How to load a user using this `UserJSONImpl` text? I need something like the following:

```
User user = new User(UserJSONImpl);
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think relying directly on `toString()` for this is a bad idea because changes to this method are out of your control. For example, what if the format changes or a new field is added? How do you know when you come to deserializing the data?

You could use a library to write the `User` objects in a standard format, for example use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to write JSON - but it's still not nice, you have to deal with `UserJSONImpl` objects which is an internal representation of `User`.

Either way, you could still be exposed to the risk of changes in the `User` object. I would consider using the `User` objects to build an object relevant the problem domain, and then persist these objects.

The idea is that the component that's responsible for the `Twitter4J User -> problem domain object` conversion can handle different `Twitter4J User` objects and provide a consistent view for your application. Although without more context this may be complete overkill, you should be able to judge this better. I hope this helps somewhat!

Comment: Why not `Twitter4j` does not have an official function to initialize the `User` with its own output? Is that a weird question?

Comment: @zagy From the library's point of view the only source of `User` objects is from Twitter, so it hides the construction (e.g. in `UserJSONImpl`). The expectation is you will consume objects created by the library and not build them yourself.